# Как оформить цикл по опциональным параметрам argparse

Tags: python, argparse

В поисках помощи, так как столкнулся с непониманием, как правильно оформить цикл, который будет обрабатывать входные аргументы, которые я ввожу через терминал. Задача состоит в том, чтобы на основе введенных аргументов записать подходящие под условия строки из одного CSV фала в другой.

У меня реализован вариант с вводом или всех параметров, или никакого (что приведет к остановке программы). Я подозреваю что это должен быть цикл, так как у меня изначально реализован сбор данных в список, который потом проверяется на соответствие условий, но поняв как сделать этот цикл с опциональными параметрами, в дальнейшем можно будет избавиться от выгрузки полного списка в память и записывать конкретную строку, которая подходит под условия цикла.

Я пытался сделать вариант с условиями для опциональных параметров, для той реализации которая у меня, но выдает ошибку

> TypeError: descriptor 'upper' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object

потому что не переданный аргумент не может быть обработан условием.
Буду бесконечно благодарён за любой ответ, спасибо!

```
import argparse
import csv


def check_args():
    for args in args_list:
        if args is None:
            args_list.remove(args)


def make_title():
    name_file = ''
    templist = []
    for var in args_list:
        templist.append(var)
    name_file = name_file + '-'.join(templist) + ".csv"
    return name_file


def read_csv():
    results = []
    with open('tz_opendata.csv', 'r+') as File:
        reader = csv.DictReader(File, delimiter=';')
        for line in reader:

            if line["BRAND"] == str.upper(args.brand) and line["MAKE_YEAR"] == str.upper(args.year) and \
                    line["FUEL"] == str.upper(args.fuel) and line["COLOR"] == str.upper(args.color):
                results.append(line)

                # print(line)

    return results


def write_csv(fieldnames, data):
    with open(make_title(), "w+", newline='') as csv_file:

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
    print('~~~DONE~~~')


def make_haader():
    result = read_csv()

    if args.reg_num == 'yes':
        fieldnames = ['D_REG', 'BRAND', 'MODEL', 'MAKE_YEAR', 'COLOR', 'FUEL', 'N_REG_NEW']
    else:
        fieldnames = ['D_REG', 'BRAND', 'MODEL', 'MAKE_YEAR', 'COLOR', 'FUEL']

    temp_list = []

    for values in result[1:]:
        inner_dict = dict(zip(fieldnames, values))
        temp_list.append(inner_dict)

    write_csv(fieldnames, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='CAR DATA 1.0', description='Know car data')
    parser.add_argument('o', default='tz_opendata.csv', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--brand', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--year', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--fuel', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--color', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--reg_num', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    argsdict = vars(args)
    args_list = [argsdict['brand'], argsdict['year'], argsdict['color'], argsdict['fuel'], argsdict['reg_num']]
    finlist = []
    if all(args is None for i in args_list):
        print("~~~NOT ENOUGTH ARGS~~~")
    else:
        check_args()
        make_haader()
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться [таким трюком](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616778/case-insensitive-argparse-choices#comment43678050_27616814):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    upper_str = str.upper
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='CAR DATA 1.0', description='Know car data')
    parser.add_argument('o', default='tz_opendata.csv', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--brand', type=upper_str)
    parser.add_argument('--year', type=upper_str)
    parser.add_argument('--fuel', type=upper_str)
    parser.add_argument('--color', type=upper_str)
    parser.add_argument('--reg_num', type=upper_str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

После этого `argparse` сам приведет все параметры, созданные с `type=upper_str` к *верхнему регистру*.

Comment: Трюк удался, но при введении нескольких опциональных параметров (а не всех), все так же ломается и выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'brand', если опциональны параметр --brand не введен.

Comment: @DanilChurko, ну так сделайте дефолтные значения для опциональных параметров если вы хотите их использовать даже в том случае когда они не вводятся

Answer (score 2):

Ну, так если навскидку, то каждое такое сравнение:

```
line["BRAND"] == str.upper(args.brand) and ...
```

Нужно заменить на такое:

```
(args.brand == None or line["BRAND"] == str.upper(args.brand)) and ...
```

Тогда такие сравнения будут истинны если агрумент не задан, либо задан и сравнение с полем выполняется. Ошибки с `upper` при этом уже не будет, потому что если в выражении с `or` истинна левая часть, то правая часть уже не проверяется и не выполняется.

Только не забудьте взять каждое выражение в скобки, потому что без скобок все операторы `and` выполнятся раньше чем операторы `or` (у операторов `and` больше приоритет чем у `or`).

Comment: Попробовал, но при подобном условии оно не записывает вообще никакие данные в новый csv файл, так как он просто пропускает линию и не отбирает ее по условию. Тут больше вопрос не в обработке NoneType, так как параметры с None я удалю из исходного списка параметров, а в том как опционально обрабатывать не все введенные параметры. Если будет введен только --brand и --year к примеру.